# Nested resources sharing same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application, I want to make it so it's possible to manage sellers commissions within a product or the seller itself, so my routes look like this:

```ruby
resources :sellers do  
  resources :commissions  
end

resources :products do
  resources :commissions
end
```

and my URLs will be like:

```ruby
/products/:product_id/commissions/:id(.:format)
/sellers/:seller_id/commissions(.:format)
```

But how can I, inside my CommissionsController know when the request is comming from a Product or a Seller so I can set my commissions based on product_id or seller_id?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check for the presence of either `params[:product_id]` or `params[:seller_id]`:

```
#app/controllers/commissions_controller.rb
class CommissionsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_model

   def index
      @commissions = @model.find @id
   end

   private

   def set_model
       case true
        when params[:seller_id]
          model = "Seller"
        when params[:product_id]
          model = "Product"
      end
      @model = model.constantize
      @id = model
   end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

you could try:

```
resources :sellers, model: 'Seller' do  
  resources :commissions  
end

resources :products, model: 'Products' do
  resources :commissions
end
```

then in controller get `model` and `id` liek this:

```
model = params[:model].constantize
id = params[params[:model].foreign_key]
```