# One action for multiple routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new user in creating web using rails. I get problems in routes rails. I have 3 models. `Student`, `Teacher`, and `Class`.

```
Student 
  has_many class

Teacher
  has_many class

Class
  belongs_to student
  belongs_to teacher
```

In routes.rb:

```
resources: students do
  resources: classes
end

resources: teachers do
  resources: classes
end
```

My problem appears when I call

```
students/1/classes or teachers/1/classes
```

Both of them call

> action index in class controller

My purpose is showing data class depends on teacher id and data classes depends on student id

How can I create a differences when it call

> action index in class controller

?

Thanks

Comment: the same question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611621/nested-resources-sharing-same-controller

Comment: Which version you're exactly using Rails 3 or 4??

Answer (score 1):

check on presence of params as the following:

```
def index
  if params[:student_id]
     @object = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  else
     @object = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
  end
  @classes = @object.classes
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The two options you have are:

> 1. Identify the option in the routes itself
> 2. Identify the data in your controller with [conditional logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming))

In fact, both of these methods will use conidtional logic - it just depends on which method 
you use as to how you'll determine how to determine the output:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :students do
   resources :classes, model: "Student"
end

resources :teachers do
   resources :classes, model: "Teacher"
end

#app/controllers/classes_controller.rb
class ClassesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_parent, only: :index

   def index
      # @classes will already be set!
   end

   private

   def set_parent
      id = params[:student_id] || params[:teacher_id]
      if params[:model].exists?
         model = params[:model]
      else
         model = "Student" if params[:student_id]
         model = "Teacher" if params[:teacher_id]
      end
      @model = model.constantize
      @parent = @model.find id
      @classes = @parent.send model.lowercase.pluralize
   end
end
```